# Anime Identification of a small house in a field, two siblings, and a flying ship

Tags: story-identification, anime

It has been years, but at one point I remember seeing a part of an anime on TV in which there was a lonely small house in the middle of a field on either a hill or a floating island. I remember the grass blowing in the wind.

It was clear the young siblings, boy and younger sister, were trying to escape or stay away from the flying ship? Magic may also have been involved? And I seem to remember the girl was more of a target?

Additional small details:
The boy had black hair, the girl had blond hair.
Their parents were absent/dead.
There was some sort of "vilain" on board the flying ship, a young man. The emphasis on the "bad guy" was definitely there, it was an established, individual character.

What it is not: *Howl's Moving Castle*, it was definitely intended for a more mature audience than Howl's, drawn in a style that was only slightly different, definitely less childlike.
Also not *Castle in the Sky*, more like Howl's than *Castle in the Sky*. The scene definitely resembled the proposed scene, but is not that one. There were no flowers in the field, mostly just grass.

Comment: If you have a few minutes to spare, consider having a look at this checklist about [_"how to ask a good (anime/manga) Story-ID question"_](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/40711) to help you remember other important details, and [edit] them in the question.

Comment: [Castle in the Sky?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ykEy-yPBFc)

Answer (score 5):

Could this be a half-remembered memory of *[Howl's Moving Castle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Howl%27s_Moving_Castle_(film))*?

Specifically the scene where Howl gifts Sophie his old cottage in a [field full of flowers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBQop.jpg). There are a few scenes of grass and flowers blowing in the wind. Howl and Sophie are soon attacked by an airship full of flying Blobbmen.

They aren't siblings, and Sophie does appear older (for reasons the movie explains) at certain points during the scene. Their hair colour kind of matches your recollection: Howl (the boy) has black hair, and Sophie (the girl) has grey hair. There's also no real mention of either of their parents as far as I can remember.

The villain on board the ship could have been either the aforementioned Blobbmen spilling out of the airship, or it could have been the scene where Sophie meets the  King of Ingary. The King doesn't appear too elderly, and he enters the scene landing in a [sort of "standing airship"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CA5Mi.jpg)